# ERROR 1064: Cannot execute while loop in mysql using variables

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I'd like to run the below query to insert into a table in a loop:

```
SET @maxid =  ( select max( length( id ) ) from article ) ;
SET @x=1;
WHILE @x<= @maxid DO
 INSERT INTO `article_responder` 
   (article_id, username, reply_id)
   SELECT @x, p.username, p.id
   FROM article AS a, post AS p
   WHERE a.id=@x AND p.article_id=@x ;
 SET  @x = @x + 1; 
 END WHILE;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END WHILE' at line
```

Notice that `article_id` can not be auto incremented, because the bussiness loginc requires that after inserting the data, the next row in `article_responder`  can be about any article. So I had no idea how to fill  `article_responder` with usual joins.

How can I fix it?

Comment: In mysql you can only code while loops in stored programs.(procedures,functions,triggers,events)

Comment: @P.Salmon so how would you rewrite the above snippet in a non-loop format?

Comment: Care to describe what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Sure. It is supposed to fetch fields from `article` and `post` and insert them in `article_responder` with the login described in the loop. The query should go through all article rows.

Comment: I am baffled by the role article_id has in this. Sample data would help clarify,

Comment: @P.Salmon it's difficult to provide data. The scenario is basically this: I have an existing blog with its comments. Now I'd like to add a new `blog_responder` table to hold  the name of people who commented on each blog, so that the name can be listed below that blog.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just making `article_id` a primary key auto increment column, and then doing the following `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO article_responder (username, reply_id)
SELECT p.username, p.id
FROM post p
INNER JOIN article a
    ON a.id = p.article_id;
```

Note that the logic `WHERE a.id=@x AND p.article_id=@x` is equivalent to saying that `a.id = p.article_id`.

Comment: Well the bussiness logic does not allow `article_id` to be auto-incremented. It should allow any `article_id` to come next.

Comment: Then maybe you should edit your question and explain that business logic, because it strikes me as an unusual requirement.

Comment: You didn't really explain the requirement, you just stated it again.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Here is the point:  I have an existing blog with its comments. Now I'd like to add a new blog_responder table to hold the name of people who commented on each blog, so that the names can be listed below that blog. The blog ids are not be auto incremental, as some of them are already deleted.